# What UK online newspaper portal to watch / follow?

Tags: united-kingdom, brexit, foreign-policy, local-government

I'm a person with social liberal views and I recently moved from Hungary to the United Kingdom. In hungarian I usually read Index.hu and 444.hu, and sometimes hvg.hu and other left, liberal voices. 
While existed I occasionally bought Népszabadság and I was a regular buyer in the early 2000s.

My question is what are the main left, liberal sources to read and follow in the UK to understand local and global politics better?

Comment: [OpenDemocracy.net](https://www.opendemocracy.net/) is useful - they tend to be more European in scope.

Comment: I cannot consider this either an answer and a regular newspaper / new portal.

Comment: Which is why I posted it as a comment rather than an answer; I also said I found it 'useful'; you may not. Its not a regular newspaper for sure but it is a news portal and I have found it useful to understand 'local and global politics'.

Comment: With the OP's edit, it might be possible to generate a reasonably sourced taxonomy of the political colours of the UK media, possibly as a community answer. If that's the intention, it would help to edit the title question as well.

Comment: Yougov have some polling data on newspapers for example: https://yougov.co.uk/news/2017/03/07/how-left-or-right-wing-are-uks-newspapers/

Comment: I created a separate question for that.
https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/26834/what-are-the-political-colours-of-different-media-outlets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The leading left/liberal news site in the UK is [The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/uk).

[BBC News](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news) has a remit for non-partisan news coverage, and is worth following as well.

Other sites exist of course, but the above two should be a good start for a newcomer to the UK.

Comment: Although to understand the  current state of British politics, it might be better to read the (very right-wing) Daily Mail as well.

Comment: I also like to get such suggestions. I won't read right-wing news everyday but it's good to know what is what.

Comment: BBC News has a remit for non-partisan coverage... but is firmly partisan.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend the Guardian to my worst enemy, but I suppose the real question behind this post is "what newspaper willi agree with most?"

Comment: @Ben BBC gets regularly accused of favoring the opposite sides by all political sides, so I guess they are doing a good job.

Comment: That is because BBC bias is not across the traditional left/right divide. So people on both the left and right periodically see "bias" they disagree with and erroneously infer the whole output is biased along that axis. It is still biased - just along a different axis, or indeed axes.